# Inconsistent behaviour when cancelling different kinds of Asyncs

Tags: f#

I have problems with seemingly inconsistent behavior when cancelling different kinds of Asyncs.

To reproduce the problem, let's says there is a function that takes a list of "jobs" (Async<_> list), waits for them to complete and prints their results. The function also gets a cancellation token so it can be cancelled:

```
let processJobs jobs cancel =
  Async.Start(async {
    try
      let! results = jobs |> Async.Parallel
      printfn "%A" results
    finally
      printfn "stopped"
  }, cancel)
```

The function is called like that:

```
let jobs = [job1(); job2(); job3(); job4(); job5()]
use cancel = new CancellationTokenSource()

processJobs jobs cancel.Token
```

And somewhat later it is cancelled:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000)
printfn "cancelling..."
cancel.Cancel()
```

When the cancellation token source is cancelled, the function should execute the finally-block and print "stopped".

**That works fine for job1, 2 and 3, but doesn't work when there is a job4 or job5 in the list.**

**Job1** just Async.Sleeps:

```
let job1() = async {
  do! Async.Sleep 1000000
  return 10
}
```

**Job2** starts some async childs and waits for them:

```
let job2() = async {
  let! child1 = Async.StartChild(async {
    do! Async.Sleep 1000000
    return 10
  })

  let! child2 = Async.StartChild(async {
    do! Async.Sleep 1000000
    return 10
  })

  let! results = [child1; child2] |> Async.Parallel
  return results |> Seq.sum
}
```

**Job3** waits for some ugly wait handle that's set by some even uglier thread:

```
let job3() = async {
  use doneevent = new ManualResetEvent(false)

  let thread = Thread(fun () -> Thread.Sleep(1000000); doneevent.Set() |> ignore)
  thread.Start()

  do! Async.AwaitWaitHandle(doneevent :> WaitHandle) |> Async.Ignore

  return 30
}
```

**Job4** posts to and waits for a reply from a MailboxProcessor:

```
let job4() = async {
  let worker = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox -> async {
    let! (msg:AsyncReplyChannel<int>) = inbox.Receive()
    do! Async.Sleep 1000000
    msg.Reply 40
  })

  return! worker.PostAndAsyncReply (fun reply -> reply) // <- cannot cancel this
}
```

**Job5** waits for a Task (or TaskCompletionSource):

```
let job5() = async {
  let tcs = TaskCompletionSource<int>()

  Async.Start(async {
    do! Async.Sleep 1000000
    tcs.SetResult 50
  })

  return! (Async.AwaitTask tcs.Task) // <- cannot cancel this
}
```

**Why can Job1, 2 and 3 be cancelled ("stopped" gets printed), while Job4 and 5 make the function hang "forever"?**

So far I always relied on F# to handle cancellation behind the scenes - as long as I'm in async-blocks and use !s (let!, do!, return!,...) everything should be fine.. but that doesn't seem to be the case all the time.

[Quote](http://tomasp.net/blog/async-csharp-differences.aspx/):

> In F# asynchronous workflows, the CancellationToken object is passed
>   around automatically under the cover. This means that we don't have to
>   do anything special to support cancellation. When running asynchronous
>   workflow, we can give it cancellation token and everything will work
>   automatically.

Complete code is available here: http://codepad.org/euVO3xgP

**EDIT**

I noticed that piping an async through Async.StartAsTask followed by Async.AwaitTask makes it cancelable in all cases.

i.e. for Job4 that means changing the line:

```
return! worker.PostAndAsyncReply (fun reply -> reply)
```

to:

```
return! cancelable <| worker.PostAndAsyncReply (fun reply -> reply)
```

With cancelable being:

```
let cancelable (x:Async<_>) = async {
  let! cancel = Async.CancellationToken
  return! Async.StartAsTask(x, cancellationToken = cancel) |> Async.AwaitTask
}
```

The same works for making Job5 cancelable.

But.. that's just a workaround and I can hardly put that around each call to an unknown Async<_>.

Answer (score 1):

Only the Async. methods handle using the default CancellationToken themselves.

In your MailboxProcessor example the cancel should go on the Start method

```
let! ct= Async.CancellationToken
use worker := MailboxProcessor.Start( theWork, ct)
```

In the TaskCompletionSource example, you are going to have to register a callback to cancel it.

```
let! ct = Async.CancellationToken
use canceler = ct.Register( fun () -> tcs.TrySetCanceled() |> ignore )
```

Comment: Passing the cancellation token to MailboxProcessor.Start only cancels "theWork". But worker.PostAndAsyncReply still blocks and never returns.